# Blank image (frame buffer)

Tags: java, libgdx, nvidia, intel, windows-7-x64

I have a really annoying problem which I'm pretty sure is due to the hybrid graphics on my laptop in some way....

I have a dell 15r laptop with hybrid nvidia/intel graphics.

If I have an external monitor plugged into my HDMI port when I run anything from libGDX I just get a blank screen the program is running fine, but nothing appears/displayed.  So I can click on my application and it works correctly, however I cannot see anything.

If I run it just on the laptop then plug the monitor in half way through, it carries on running as normal.
If I start running it on the monitor but then unplug the monitor so it reverts to the laptop screen, it displays nothing again.

Using this...

```
System.out.println(Gdx.graphics.getGL20().glGetString(GL20.GL_VENDOR));
```

The program reports

> NVIDIA Corporation

Comment: Try experimenting with "forcing" your app (or OS even) to one GPU or the other (I think you can do this with the Nvidia control panel).  Is your app full-screen or windowed?

Comment: tried running it in full screen mode or not.  I've played wtih all the settings in nVid panel, but really without knowing exactly why/what the problem maybe I guess I'm shooting blind :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it.

Upgraded to latest NVidia drivers and everything seems fine.